# TypeError: NoneType object is not iterable

Tags: python

When I am iterating through my variable it gives me an error which I show as below.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ZHEN YUAN\Desktop\东航第一步\wen2.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in Names:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my answer. I'm trying to answer your additional question, but it's hard, because part of your original question has been deleted. Could you please put the code that caused the error back in the question? That would also make it easier for others to make sense of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `wenjian()` does not have any `return` statements, so it will always return `None`, by default. That's why `Names = wenjian(file)` assigns the value `None` to `Names`, and so you can't iterate over `Names` with the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, how can i change。 Only need and one 'rerurn wenjian'

Answer (score 0):

import os

def wenjian(file):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(file):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root,file)
            print (filename[-28:])

file = ("C:\Users\ZHEN YUAN\Desktop\东航try")

Names = wenjian(file)

for i in Names:
    print (i[1])

```
PS C:\Users\ZHEN YUAN> & python "c:/Users/ZHEN YUAN/Desktop/东航第一步/wen2.py"
\Desktop\东航try\C2002455.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ZHEN YUAN/Desktop/东航第一步/wen2.py", line 14, in <module>
    for i in Names:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```